# Overlapping labels in HighCharts on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have spline chart, with dateTime xAxis and more than 3k points in each of 2 categories: http://jsfiddle.net/jk171505/dmmhL5ha/7/

Is there a way, other than tickInterval, to prevent overlapping labels on xAxis?
I tried to use tickInterval but this isn't the option, as data points are irregular and amount varies (sometimes it's data for period of 2 weeks, sometimes 2 years):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ["test1", "test"],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 31,
```

Comment: Why don't you use **`rotation`**? http://jsfiddle.net/dmmhL5ha/8/

Comment: my jsfiddle is just an example to illustrate the problem, in the real chart there is just no place to display rotated dates in the format like "December 12, 2014"

Comment: Highcharts will make place, try it. And if you don't want your labels rotated or reduced, how do you suggest they fit??

Comment: I know that chart will be scaled to place labels underneath, not an option. Well, I expected them to be placed automatically, the same way as it works without categories. Do you suggest that without rotation, all 3k labels have to be displayed? So there is now build mechanism that will display just some of them and position them automatically?

Comment: Exactly, categorized axes labels does not work like datetime axes. You need to either tell the chart which ones to show or it will show them all in anyway possible. The best way I think is the rotation. Or you can use formatter or step to select which labels to show.

Comment: I would really like to see the expected result - do you have some mockup? First of all, you are trying to use categorized axis and setting `type: 'datetime'`. You can't have in Highcharts two types of the axis on one axis.

Comment: I just would like to show 2 sets of data on the same axis. Each set contains data for different period of time, but they overlap, i.e.: 1st set contains data mar 1st - sep 1st, 2nd contains data for jan 1st - dec 1st. Timestamps are irregular, meaning data might not be available for every day (1-5 days gaps). Categories are not required, but the problem remains even they are removed (in the example above).

Comment: Here is the example with categories removed: http://jsfiddle.net/jk171505/dmmhL5ha/9/, and here is modified demo from highcharts.com: http://jsfiddle.net/jk171505/n9xvof2y/ , http://d.pr/i/1k2J1 (where all what I changed is the date format, and label alignment). Both cases demonstrates the same problem

Comment: But for me these labels don't overlap. Tried browser window resizing -  the same output. Maybe it's connected to the OS/browser? I can see ellipsis on the labels (extra dots) when overlapping could happen.

Comment: Resize event fixes the issue in most cases. After you resize, run the script one more time using 'Run' menu item. But in my case (Mac OS X 10.10.2, Chrome 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit)) it's reproducible every single time: http://d.pr/i/QPFw, http://d.pr/i/177Gu

Comment: Ok, in case you use different format for labels, I think it's good idea to set `tickPixelInterval` - bigger than label width, to make sure there is enough space between items, see: http://jsfiddle.net/dmmhL5ha/10/

Comment: @PawełFus thanks, `tickPixelInterval` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set `tickPixelInterval` - bigger than label width, to make sure there is enough space between items [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmmhL5ha/10/).